# Is it possible to install joomla on a windows server?

Tags: php, windows, server, joomla

Is it possible to install joomla  on a windows server and what might be the difficulties of going about and doing so. Our client has a windows dedicated box and they want joomla placed on their server.

Comment: I usually develop in windows environment, and joomla was also one of them. It just worked fine.

Comment: so do you setup apache on the server and just upload it to the webroot. almost as if you were installing it locally on a windows machine ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - see http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html

Comment: would it be just like installing apache on a local machine. How is permissions setup ? Is that different ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Microsoft's [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to [install Joomla 1.6 on a Windows server](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/joomla16.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The page that Tadeck referred to, http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html, recommends you use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com) which bundles together Apache, MySQL and PHP in one install. Once you've installed that the [Quickstart Guide](http://help.joomla.org/ghop/feb2008/task048/joomla_15_quickstart.pdf) will help you (though it talks about using XAMPP, but the previous page says it isn't for live sites). You basically unzip the Joomla install to a directory, and then go to the URL http://localhost/joomla15 to finish off.